# Detecting how bright is the sun using a photodiode

Tags: visible-light, infrared-radiation

Basically I'm trying to control the moment when I turn on the lights using a photodiode. Let's say when the sun illuminance is 10lx, the photodiode will read a given value in $\frac{W}{cm^2}$. Given the luminosity function $v(\lambda)$ the photodiode sensitivity (mainly infrared) curve and the sun spectrum is there a way to find this correlation?
I tried to integrate $v(\lambda)$ multiplied by the sun spectrum and the same for the photodiode sensitivity and found a ratio which does not fit to my measurements.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by Luminosity function. Did you quantity them or have a proper numerical expression for each of them?

Comment: Sorry, the luminosity function is related to the human eye sensitivity. These values are tabulated and provided by the CIE.

Comment: Here your detector will use light directly from the sun. You don't use you eyes to do anything in your device right? Then, there is no link to what you eye sees and therefore luminosity function has nothing to do with this calculation

Comment: @latitude, the luminosity function is related to when we'd want to turn on the lights to make it easier to see things around us.

Comment: @Hagan, you can buy a photodiode that's calibrated relative to luminosity rather than radiative flux. Or you can make the turn-on threshold adjustable, and adjust it based on your own perception of brightness. But this is more of an engineering question than physics.

Comment: @ThePhoton The photodiode is behind a diffuser, only transparent to IR. I agree that the question is related to an engineering problem but with physical background.